# Can I dualboot Iphone/Ipod Touch with Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, iphone

I just recently dualbooted my macbook 3,1 with Lubuntu, since it was getting slow. Can I do the same with my Ipod Touch 4th generation?

Answer (score 1):

//////////////////absolutely no.